# Named return variable not getting set in for loop

Tags: function, variables, go, scope

I have a GoLang function that tries to set some named return variables inside a **FOR** loop.  It looks something like this:

```
func (dbs *myClient) DoStuff() (response []byte, e error) {
    for i:=0;i<5;i+=1 {
        response, e = dbs.doNetworkThing()
        if e == nil {
            break;
        }
    }
    return response, e
}
```

Basically what I'd like to do is set the return variables `response` and `e` to first result from doNetworkThing() that does not fail.

The problem is that `response` and `e` get reset once I exit from the for loop.  What's the correct idiomatic way of doing something like this in GoLang?

I really want to use named return variables since they make things easier to read (I would consider something like this to be an ugly solution).

```
// Seems to be an ugly solution - would prefer using named return vars
func (dbs *myClient) DoStuff() ([]byte, error) {
    var response []byte
    var e error
    for i:=0;i<5;i+=1 {
        response, e := dbs.doNetworkThing()
        if e == nil {
            break;
        }
    }
    return response, e
}
```

Comment: Your loop logic does not seem to match what you described as the desired behaviour. Breaking on `e == nil` does not equal to "latest result", it's more like the "first result that didn't fail". And if that's what you're looking for you can just `return` from inside the loop, which is a lot nicer than using a `break`; although what's nicer, or what's uglier is **subjective**.

Comment: Edited for clarity (I actually meant "first result that doesn't fail").

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted - if it's a dupe, please call that out.

Comment: While I did not downvote myself, my guess for why someone might downvote your post would be that; your first example code *actually works the way you want it to*, and the second part of your question could lead to subjective discussion on what's readable or uglier which SO is not the appropriate place for. https://play.golang.org/p/V5c-l3PXHE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below seems to work (compiles). tested [here](https://play.golang.org/p/eVMVDiQv0h).

```
func (dbs *myClient) DoStuff() (response []byte, e error) {
    for i:=0;i<5;i+=1 {
        response, e = dbs.doNetworkThing()
        if e == nil {
            break;
        }
    }
    return
}
```

What I did:

1. I removed the `response` and `e` declaration as it is already declared the moment you named your return values.
2. changed `:=` to `=` because (again) the variable is already declared
3. changed `return response, e` to `return` since the return values are named

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example you may exit from the cycle: thus solving 2 tacks to break the loop and return values.

```
func (dbs *myClient) DoStuff() (response []byte, e error) {
    for i:=0;i<5;i+=1 {
        response, e = dbs.doNetworkThing()
        if e == nil {
            return response, e
        }
    }

}
```